# Yii2 notification widget class not found

Tags: notifications, yii2, widget, yii2-basic-app

I'm trying to use "machour's" notification widget

But somehow I can't even call class: NotificationWidget in my code

It says that "Class is not found"

I'm using yii2-basic-template, how can I call that Class ?

*edit:*

i tried to create directory: backend/components and tried

*use backend/components/Notification;*

But i use basic template so i don't think it's right

https://github.com/machour/yii2-notifications

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
        'language' => 'en',
        'bootstrap' => ['languagepicker'],
        'modules' => [
            'notifications' => [
                'class' => 'machour\yii2\notifications\NotificationsModule',
                // Point this to your own Notification class
                // See the "Declaring your notifications" section below
                'notificationClass' => 'app\models\Notification',
                // Allow to have notification with same (user_id, key, key_id)
                // Default to FALSE
                'allowDuplicate' => false,
                // This callable should return your logged in user Id
                'userId' => function() {
                    return \Yii::$app->user->id;
                }
            ],
          'redactor' => 'yii\redactor\RedactorModule',
          'class' => 'yii\redactor\RedactorModule',
          'uploadDir' => '@webroot/uploads',
          'uploadUrl' => '../web/uploads',
      ],
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
          'languagepicker' => [
            'class' => 'lajax\languagepicker\Component',
            'languages' => ['en-US', 'vi']                   // List of available languages (icons only)
        ],
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'hhs9xband',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => '',
                'username' => '',
                'password' => '',
                'port' => '587',
            ],
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
        /*
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
        */
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];
}

return $config;
```

This is the code when i call it:

```
use backend\components\Notification
<?= NotificationsWidget::widget([
    'theme' => NotificationsWidget::THEME_GROWL,
    'clientOptions' => [
        'location' => 'br',
    ],
    'counters' => [
        '.notifications-header-count',
        '.notifications-icon-count'
    ],
    'listSelector' => '#notifications',
]);

?>
```

And this is the code inside folder: backend/components:

```
namespace backend\components;

use Yii;
use common\models\Meeting;
use common\models\Message;
use machour\yii2\notifications\models\Notification as BaseNotification;

class Notification extends BaseNotification
{

    /**
     * A new message notification
     */
    const KEY_NEW_MESSAGE = 'new_message';
    /**
     * A meeting reminder notification
     */
    const KEY_MEETING_REMINDER = 'meeting_reminder';
    /**
     * No disk space left !
     */
    const KEY_NO_DISK_SPACE = 'no_disk_space';

    /**
     * @var array Holds all usable notifications
     */
    public static $keys = [
        self::KEY_NEW_MESSAGE,
        self::KEY_MEETING_REMINDER,
        self::KEY_NO_DISK_SPACE,
    ];

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        switch ($this->key) {
            case self::KEY_MEETING_REMINDER:
                return Yii::t('app', 'Meeting reminder');

            case self::KEY_NEW_MESSAGE:
                return Yii::t('app', 'You got a new message');

            case self::KEY_NO_DISK_SPACE:
                return Yii::t('app', 'No disk space left');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        switch ($this->key) {
            case self::KEY_MEETING_REMINDER:
                $meeting = Meeting::findOne($this->key_id);
                return Yii::t('app', 'You are meeting with {customer}', [
                    'customer' => $meeting->customer->name
                ]);

            case self::KEY_NEW_MESSAGE:
                $message = Message::findOne($this->key_id);
                return Yii::t('app', '{customer} sent you a message', [
                    'customer' => $meeting->customer->name
                ]);

            case self::KEY_NO_DISK_SPACE:
                // We don't have a key_id here
                return 'Please buy more space immediately';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getRoute()
    {
        switch ($this->key) {
            case self::KEY_MEETING_REMINDER:
                return ['meeting', 'id' => $this->key_id];

            case self::KEY_NEW_MESSAGE:
                return ['message/read', 'id' => $this->key_id];

            case self::KEY_NO_DISK_SPACE:
                return 'https://aws.amazon.com/';
        };
    }

}
```

Those codes are for Advance template, i think i need to change something to make it works on Basic template

Comment: update your question and add your  your_basic_app/config/web-php  ..please

Comment: @scaisEdge I updated config/web code

Comment: @scaisEdge I updated the codes, which should work in Advance template. There's no backend folder for Basic template

Comment: have you found a solution  ?

Answer (score 0):

Due the fact you are using basic template you should add the configuration elements not in backend/config (this is for advanced  template) 
but in you application directory /config/web.php

eg:

```
      config = [
        'id' => 'your_app_id',
        'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
        'bootstrap' => ['log'],
        'components' => [
             ......
        ],
        // ...
        'modules' => [
            'notifications' => [
                'class' => 'machour\yii2\notifications\NotificationsModule',
                // Point this to your own Notification class
                // See the "Declaring your notifications" section below
                'notificationClass' => 'app\models\Notification',
                // Allow to have notification with same (user_id, key, key_id)
                // Default to FALSE
                'allowDuplicate' => false,
                // This callable should return your logged in user Id
                'userId' => function() {
                    return \Yii::$app->user->id;
                }
            ],
            // your other modules ..
        ],

    ];
```

and you should change the reference to backend (that is for anvanced template) to you basic directory and namespace in use  ..  be careful to specify the correct namespace declaration in your extension of this form and its value in `use` statements

you should move your code in backend/components: in your  app\models\

and change the namespace

```
namespace backend\components;
```

to

```
 namespace app\models;
```

in  this way you add the    Notification class to your Models

and  change the `use backend\components\Notification`  to `app\models\Notification`  also where you use the widget

Comment: I actually added module to config/web

Comment: once you have the right config you must adapt the correct namespace and use in you code  ..

Comment: Can you describe it in more details,

I need to use `use` to call the code, but which directory behide `use`

Comment: I tried but it still says `Class 'NotificationsWidget' not found`