# Yii2 machour NotificationsWidget class not found

Tags: notifications, yii2, widget, yii2-advanced-app

We are trying to run "machour" notification widget in Yii2-Advanced template. We could successfully install the extension through composer.

We are getting the following class error: 
Class 'NotificationsWidget' not found.

The above problem is still existing [Yii2 notification widget class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43290812/yii2-notification-widget-class-not-found).

We are calling following code in layouts folder:

```
use common\models\Notification;
    <?php NotificationsWidget::widget([
        'theme' => NotificationsWidget::THEME_GROWL,
        'clientOptions' => [
            'location' => 'br',
        ],
        'counters' => [
            '.notifications-header-count',
            '.notifications-icon-count'
        ],
        'markAllSeenSelector' => '#notification-seen-all',
        'listSelector' => '#notifications',
    ]);

    ?>
```

And this is the code inside folder: common/models:

```
<?php
namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\db\Expression;
use machour\yii2\notifications\models\Notification as BaseNotification;

class Notification extends BaseNotification
{

    /**
     * A new message notification
     */
    const KEY_NEW_MESSAGE = 'new_message';
    /**
     * A meeting reminder notification
     */
    const KEY_MEETING_REMINDER = 'meeting_reminder';
    /**
     * No disk space left !
     */
    const KEY_NO_DISK_SPACE = 'no_disk_space';

    /**
     * @var array Holds all usable notifications
     */
    public static $keys = [
        self::KEY_NEW_MESSAGE,
        self::KEY_MEETING_REMINDER,
        self::KEY_NO_DISK_SPACE,
    ];

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        switch ($this->key) {
            case self::KEY_MEETING_REMINDER:
                return Yii::t('app', 'Meeting reminder');

            case self::KEY_NEW_MESSAGE:
                return Yii::t('app', 'You got a new message');

            case self::KEY_NO_DISK_SPACE:
                return Yii::t('app', 'No disk space left');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        switch ($this->key) {


            case self::KEY_NO_DISK_SPACE:
                // We don't have a key_id here
                return 'Please buy more space immediately';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getRoute()
    {
        switch ($this->key) {

            case self::KEY_NO_DISK_SPACE:
                return 'https://aws.amazon.com/';
        };
    }

}
```

and configuration code inside frontend/config:

```
'modules' => [
        'redactor' => 'yii\redactor\RedactorModule',
        'notifications' => [
            'class' => 'machour\yii2\notifications\NotificationsModule',
            // Point this to your own Notification class
            // See the "Declaring your notifications" section below
            'notificationClass' => 'common\models\Notification',
            // Allow to have notification with same (user_id, key, key_id)
            // Default to FALSE
            'allowDuplicate' => false,
            // Allow custom date formatting in database
            'dbDateFormat' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
            // This callable should return your logged in user Id
            'userId' => function() {
                return \Yii::$app->user->id;
            }
       ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `NotificationsWidget` class file path like

```
use machour\yii2\notifications\widgets\NotificationsWidget;
use common\models\Notification;

<?php NotificationsWidget::widget([
    'theme' => NotificationsWidget::THEME_GROWL,
    'clientOptions' => [
        'location' => 'br',
    ],
    'counters' => [
        '.notifications-header-count',
        '.notifications-icon-count'
    ],
    'markAllSeenSelector' => '#notification-seen-all',
    'listSelector' => '#notifications',
]);

?>
```

Refer [Yii2 notifications](https://github.com/machour/yii2-notifications)